# EWMA and EWMV unbiased estimators

Tags: statistics, average, descriptive-statistics

Good evening.

I got random variables $r_1, r_2 ... r_N$ i.i.d normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$

I also got $\lambda$ - decay factor.

I got 2 estimators:

$r_N^{*} = \frac{1 - \lambda}{1 - \lambda^N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda^{i-1} r_i$

and

$v_N = \frac{1 - \lambda^2}{2\lambda(1 - \lambda^{N-1})}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda^{i-1} (r_i - r_N^*)^2$

I need to prove that they are unbiased estimators of mean and variance respectively.

---

For the mean it is simple. By taking expectation of $r_N$ and using linearity I arrive to this:

$E[r_N^{*}] = \frac{1 - \lambda}{1 - \lambda^N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda^{i-1} E[r_i] = \mu\frac{1 - \lambda}{1 - \lambda^N}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda^{i-1} = \mu$ using the $(1 - \lambda)^N$ expansion

Now, for the variance for some reason I'm getting stuck:

$E[v_N] = \frac{1 - \lambda^2}{2\lambda(1 - \lambda^{N-1})}\sum_{i=1}^{N} \lambda^{i-1} E[(r_i - r_N^{*})^2]$

The common trick used almost everywhere is to add and subtract the mean, so:

$E[(r_i - r_N^{*})^2] = E[((r_i - \mu) - (r_N^{*} - \mu))^2] = E[(r_i - \mu)^2] + E[(r_N^{*} - \mu)^2] - 2E[(r_i - \mu)(r_N^{*} - \mu)] = 2\sigma - 2E[(r_i - \mu)(r_N^{*} - \mu)]$

How do I proceed? Directly substituing the value for $r_N$ lead me to some disastrous math which I'd rather assume is wrong.

Comment: If you mean at the beginning, then my understanding of it was the following: $E[(r_i - r_N)^2] = E[r_i^2] + E[r_N^2] - 2E[r_i r_N]$. The first one is $\mu^2 + \sigma^2$ but the other two ... the second one, I guess, is just $\mu^2$ since the unbiased estimator has no variance (right?), but now the third one: I have to substitute it into my $r_N$ expression and due to i.i.d I have to split the sum into (N-1)-sum and a singleton, and for some reason the entire result just doesn't collapse to $\sigma^2$ in the end

Comment: by "other two" I meant values of $E[r_N^2]$ and $-2E[r_i r_N]$

Comment: May I know why $E[r_N^2]$ is $\mu^2 + \sigma^2$? It is an estimator, for which I know, due to it being unbiased, that $E[r_N] = \mu$ and $Var[r_N] = 0$, so using the formula $Var[X] = E[x^2] - E[x]^2$ I derived $\mu^2$. For the factorization, you mean $E[r_i r_N] = E[r_i] E[r_N]$? For some reason I don't see why this is true. What is true though is $E[r_i r_j] = E[r_i] E[r_j]$ for $i \ne j$

Comment: oh yeah I'm very sorry for this, I'll edit the question to make it less confusing

Comment: Say you have historical daily stock returns. The idea behind decay factor is that the further the value is from today, the lesser impact it has on the resulting average and this factor is essentially a measure of the impact

Comment: Oh, its just a constant, chosen arbitrarily